# Using try catch for validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a service layer which calls a repository which accesses the dbContext.
If I catch the DbUpdateException in my service layer or in the controller, am I risking more of a performance hit than if I do something such creating my own Save method which calls the dbContext.SaveChanges method, catches the exceptions and returns a custom class that contains a list of the exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The level at which you catch the exceptions can only really impact on the size of the stack trace and what has to be unwound to get back to a stable state.  The higher the level the exception is caught, the more frames there are to the trace.

Then there is the concern of bleeding information from your data layer to your controller/service layer.  If you catch the exception in your service layer, it might tie it to a particular implementation, such as catching EF exceptions.

It would be cleaner to catch the implementation specific exceptions in that layer, and return something that is relevant to your business domain so that if you ever switch out the implementation of the dal, you don't have to recode for new exceptions in your service layer.

It's all about isolation.